# Unable to get auto incremented id

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have the following database config

```
public static final String ST_ID = "s_id";  
public static final String ST_NAME = "s_name";
public static final String ST_COURSE = "s_course";
public static final String DBCREATE_STUDENTDB = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME+" ("                  
                + "s_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "s_name VARCHAR, "
                + "s_course VARCHAR);";
        public static final int VERSION = 1;
```

Now I am trying to get the individual id

```
final ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = { StudentDB.ST_NAME, StudentDB.ST_COURSE };
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(StudentDataProvider.studentTableUri, projection, null,  null, null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

        Log.wtf("ID", ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StudentDB.ST_ID)));

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

I am getting error on this.

```
10-02 07:14:29.788: E/AndroidRuntime(2252): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

however the following code works for other column

```
Log.wtf("List", ""+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(StudentDB.ST_COURSE)));
```

what is the problem?

Comment: cursor.getColumnIndex(StudentDB.ST_ID)  return INTEGER, do not use cursor.getString(), use cursor.getInt();

Comment: That is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add your ID in your Projection Change it to :

```
final String[] projection = { StudentDB.ST_NAME, StudentDB.ST_COURSE,StudentDB.ST_ID};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final String[] projection = { StudentDB.ST_NAME, StudentDB.ST_COURSE };
```

If no ID in your projection, the cursor don't have any field called so.

Do this:

```
final String[] projection = { StudentDB.ST_ID, StudentDB.ST_NAME, StudentDB.ST_COURSE };
```

@Sardor Dushamov, was right too, if ID is autoincrement, use getInt not getString.

Answer (score 0):

See your projection String[], you didn't add the `StudentDB.ST_ID`